# How to retrieve a custom post's capability?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type

When you register a custom post type, you can specify it's capability:

```
'capability_type' => 'page',
```

Is there away to retrieve the capability_type within a page (based on the post object provided)? I don't see it listed within the post object. But maybe there's a way to retrieve by passing the post_type?

The ultimate goal is to find out whether a post is to be treated as a "page" or a "post" on the front-end, which would allow me to load different template/code parts based on that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get_post_type_object()` function accepts a post type name and returns the post type object. You can then check the `capability_type` property of this object.

Example:

```
$post     = get_post( $post_id );
$pto      = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
$cap_type = $pto->capability_type;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks! I kept searching but the only thing coming up was this function get_post_type_capabilities(), which retrieves the capabilities array.